# Friendly URL (mod-rewrite) issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, friendly-url

Hallo,

I am trying to make "nice" URL, first rule works as expected, it's turning

www.blabla.com/index.php?page=tags&tag=blabla

into

www.blabla.com/tags/blabla

but second rules doesn't works?

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&tag=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L]
```

Than you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since numbers could be considered as anything but a forward slash (`/`), you should put the article rule before the tag rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&tag=$2 [L]
```